# zsh - optimize copy, cut, paste using ctrl+c, ctrl+x, ctrl+v

Tags: zsh, xsel

I am using the following config in my `.zshrc`.

```
if [[ -t 0 && $- = *i* ]]
then
# change Ctrl+C to Ctrl+I
stty start ''
stty stop ''
stty quit ''
stty erase ''
stty kill ''
stty eof '' # Ctrl + D
stty rprnt ''
stty werase ''
stty lnext ''
stty discard ''

fi

# change Ctrl+C to Ctrl+Q
stty intr '^q'

# change Ctrl+z to Ctrl+j
stty susp '^j'

# change Ctrl+V to Ctrl+K
bindkey '^k' quoted-insert # for zle

_copy-using-xsel() {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)) then
  zle copy-region-as-kill
  printf "$CUTBUFFER" | xsel -i --clipboard
  ((REGION_ACTIVE = 0))
  fi
}

zle -N _copy-using-xsel
bindkey '^C' _copy-using-xsel # Copy text

_cut-using-xsel() {
  if ((REGION_ACTIVE)) then
       zle copy-region-as-kill
       printf "$CUTBUFFER" | xsel -i --clipboard
       zle kill-region
  fi
}

zle -N _cut-using-xsel
bindkey '^X' _cut-using-xsel # Cut text

_paste-copy-using-xsel() {
  LBUFFER+="$(xsel -b -o)"
}

zle -N _paste-copy-using-xsel
bindkey '^V' _paste-copy-using-xsel # Paste
```

It enables me to copy using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, cut using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, paste using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. However, I noticed that the operations are slow. I mean it appears to me that, it takes half a second to cut. Is it due to the use of `xsel`? How can I optimize my keybindings so that the lag is gone.

Comment: Note that `^J` is newline!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes. setting `KEYTIMEOUT=10` seems to increase the performance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what should I use instead of `((REGION_ACTIVE = 0))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

If "cut" alone is slow, it is likely that you have `^X` as a prefix to some other keybind.  You could check what bindings exist, and change the relevant ones:

```
$ bindkey | grep '\^X'
"^X^B" vi-match-bracket
"^X^F" vi-find-next-char
"^X^J" vi-join
"^X^K" kill-buffer
"^X^N" infer-next-history
"^X^O" overwrite-mode
"^X^U" undo
"^X^V" vi-cmd-mode
"^X^X" exchange-point-and-mark
"^X*" expand-word
"^X=" what-cursor-position
"^XG" list-expand
"^Xg" list-expand
"^Xr" history-incremental-search-backward
"^Xs" history-incremental-search-forward
"^Xu" undo
```

As you can see, on my system zsh has several such bindings out of the box.

If you'd prefer not to change these, then setting the `KEYTIMEOUT` environment variable to something shorter than its default 0.4s will also reduce your wait times, with the caveat that multiple-key bindings like those will require more speed to input.

---

Script quality things:

Using uncontrolled variables as the first argument to `printf` is problematic.  Since the first argument is the format string, it gets
reinterpreted and might not do what you want.

```
printf '%d'      # prints a "0" with no trailing newline
printf '%s' '%d' # prints "%d"
```

So you should use `printf '%s' "$CUTBUFFER"`.

Additionally, if you want to set `REGION_ACTIVE` to 0, you don't need parens around the assignment.  Rather than `((REGION_ACTIVE = 0))` you can just you `REGION_ACTIVE=0`.